# Perl/MySQL 'Host is not allowed' and ' failed: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server' errors?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, localhost, remote-access

I am writing a Perl script that is being executed from a remote UNIX server. The script is supposed to connect to my localhost machine, and post some data to the MySQL server running by XAMPP. 
I used the following code to initiate a connection:

```
my $dbHost = "my-machine-name";
my $dbUsername    = "root";
my $dbPassword    = "";
my $databaseName = "myDB";
my $connection = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$databaseName;host=$dbHost", 
                               $dbUsername, $dbPassword, { RaiseError => 1 } ) 
                 or die ( "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr );
```

At first I was getting:

> Host ... is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Then I [read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/access-denied.html) that I need to add the rejected host to the list of users. So I opened XAMPP Control, clicked on XAMPP->ADMIN to open phpMyAdmin, then navigated to the user table, copied the row that said host=127.0.0.1 and then modified the 127.0.0.1 to the rejected IP I was getting. Then I opened XAMPP Control again, stopped both Apache and MySQL, and then started them.

Now, I am getting:

> DBI connect('myDB;host=my-machine-name','root',...)
>   failed: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by
>   server; consider upgrading MySQL client at ...

I tried changing the hostname from the string-name to the IPv4 Address, and still got the same error. Also tried adding the `:3306` to the end of the host, but got the same error.

Any idea what I can do to access a localhosted MySQL from a remote server?

Comment: What version of the MySQL client and server are you using? The guidelines in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/old-client.html) are pretty clear for the error `Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server`.

Comment: XAMPP is running version 5.6.16. How do I check the other version that my PERL script is using?

Comment: `mysql -V` on the host you're trying to connect *from*.

Comment: I type it in the shell, and get mysql: command not found. Is there a special way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you have a mismatch in the password hash.  Try adding this line to your mysql conf file **old_passwords=1** then restart mysql.

Comment: What OS is on the host you're connecting from? If it's *nix, you can also try `mysql_config --version`

Comment: unix, also not found. do i need to go to the sql directory or something? or it should work from anywhere?

Comment: That means either they're not installed on your system, or they're not in your `PATH`. Try `locate mysql` and `locate mysql_config`.

Comment: still nothing, i am not sure what is the PATH.

Comment: Do you actually have the MySQL client library installed on that machine? That's what you need, at a minimum, to install `DBD::mysql`...how did you install `DBD::mysql` anyway?

Comment: it is installed on the server, because other scripts are using MySQL to upload to the database on the server. But I want to connect to my localhost server on my machine.

Comment: There's a difference between the MySQL *client* and the MySQL *server*. It's unclear what you have installed on which host so all I can say is, re-read the documentation I linked to above. If you have *clear* information about what is installed on localhost and what is installed on the remote host, please edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$server = 'your server';
$port = '3306';
$user = 'your_user';
$pass = 'your_pass';
$database = 'database';
$dbConn = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$database:$server:$port", "$user", "$pass")
or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;
```

Comment: is the $server string is my local machine name? the server where the perl is running? or localhost?

Comment: the $server is where you like to connect to.

Comment: $server is the hostname or IP address of the server where the DB is located.

Comment: so how is that any different than the first code I posted above?

Comment: host=$dbHost should be only $dbHost and better add the port 3306 to.

Comment: I tried with the port and without, the result is the same.

Comment: than your problem is elsewhere

Comment: You maybe considering adding 127.0.0.1 to your : C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts